# Is the fetchpriority attribute default now on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, attributes, hook, pagespeed

[image: screenshot of the fetchpriority attr]

As we can see the fetchpriority attribute is being used although I didn't apply that. I am using the WP rocket. As I know there is no fetchpriority option on WP rocket rocket. Seems like I am unable to find the culprit.

Maybe this feature comes default by WordPress. But I not sure as I didn't find any relevent informations.

Note: This is a elementor site.

I just want to know, is the fetchpriority feature is a default feature or not.
if yes, how do I remove them by hook or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Felix Arntz and the rest of the WordPress core performance team implemented a big optimization in 6.3. It is [written up here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/08/07/wordpress-6-3-performance-improvements/) and does use `fetchpriority`.

Its purpose is to improve time to largest contentful paint (LCP).

Comment: Hi Jones, thanks for your time.

I have read the docs. There is explained in detail about the fetchpriority and lazy load. But I didn't find anything about the background images.

In many cases, the background image is the LCP element. So, it is crucial to optimize the background image to improve the LCP score. But I didn't find anything about the background images. Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, fetchpriority is being added by default as of WordPress 6.3, to at maximum 1 image on each URL.

I worked on the feature in WordPress core. For details please see:

- https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/13/image-performance-enhancements-in-wordpress-6-3/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_loading_optimization_attributes/

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your time. I have read the docs. There is explained in detail about the fetchpriority and lazy load. But I didn't find anything about the background images. In many cases, the background image is the LCP element. So, it is crucial to optimize the background image to improve the LCP score. But I didn't find anything about the background images. Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

fetchpriority is not a default attribute in WordPress, Elementor, or WP Rocket. WordPress does not include this attribute by default in its core, nor does WP Rocket or Elementor.

The presence of such an attribute might be due to a third-party plugin maybe.

If you want to remove your attribute from the image you can create a custom function for this

```
function remove_fetchpriority($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)fetchpriority="(.*?)"(.*?)>/', '<img$1$3>', $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_fetchpriority');
```

Comment: It's in core in 6.3.